# MySqldb Error on Global name:db

Tags: python, pygtk, mysql-python

I'm put my question here, but first I searched this entire site and didn't find the correct answer for it.

I'm a noob in Python and PyGTK.

here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import MySQLdb
import sys,os
```

###delete the most of the code... left that i think is needed ... (thanks ... for the comment about code lenght) ###

```
    def basedatos(self):
        db_host = 'localhost'
        usuario = 'root'
        clave = ''
        base_de_datos = 'toco_bdd'
        db = MySQLdb.connect(user=usuario,passwd= clave,db= base_de_datos,unix_socket="/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock")

    def chequeouser(self):
        passwdcheck = txt_password.text()
        usuariover = txt_usuario.text()
        datosLogin = "SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = usuariover AND password = 'passwdcheck"

        #para Futura Referencia - QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, "hola", "tu nombre de usuario es:"+usuariover+"y tu password es" + passwdcheck,QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
        datosLogin = "SELECT * FROM t_usuarios WHERE id_usuario = 'usuario' AND password = 'password'"
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(datosLogin)


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#window.resize( 350,210)
#window.move(450,250)
#window.setWindowTitle("TM Administrador - Login")
#window.show()
loginit = entrar()
loginit.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and I'm getting this error:

> cursor = db.cursor() NameError: global name 'db' is not defined

Comment: Try to minimize the amount of code you put in your question. If you compartmentalize the problem you'll probably find out the solution to it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined 'db' inside of def basedatos(self): so when you try to access that inside of the other functions it's not defined there so you get that error. You could define that globally to resolve that error. I'm a noob myself, so not sure how 'pythonic' that is, but that's why you're getting the error anyway.

Comment: @nmjeremiah how to do it?

Comment: @mitsuzeroblackout should be a checkmark you can click under the up/down vote buttons to the left of the answer.